# How to hide mouse pointer on startup?

Tags: c++, qt, embedded, touchscreen

I have an embedded touch screen running linux and my app is Qt/C++.

I start the app with the function main which looks like this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QThread>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Create the app
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Hide the pointer
    app.setOverrideCursor( QCursor( Qt::BlankCursor ) );

    // Create main window
    MainWindow *window = new MainWindow;

    // Set up the UI and execute the App
    window->show();
    app.exec();

    // tidy up
    delete(window);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem that I have is that when I run the program the cursor is showing. But as soon as I touch the screen (the app is a full-screen app) the cursor then disappears.

I have read that it may be a simple focus issue - i.e. that my app is not in focus or some-such. How can I make sure that my app is the focus at startup?

Or

Is there anything I am doing wrong to hide the mouse pointer?

**---EDIT---**

If I remove the line `app.setOverrideCursor( QCursor( Qt::BlankCursor ) );` then I have focus on my app. So this line somehow makes my app lose focus.

So as a quick hack I put a QTimer in the MainWindow and set it for 100ms (just so that it will only get handled once the event processing starts - i.e. after app.execute()). Then I connected the timer event to a slot function that I call "getFocusOnMeNow()" which in which I have:

```
this->activateWindow();
this->setFocus();
```

And this works.

So now I would like to tidy this up. What function/slot can I call AFTER app.execute() within the MainWindow to get focus? I don't see a MainWindow::start() slot that I can overload...?

Comment: If you think that's the case, about hiding the cursor in your window's showEvent instead?

Comment: @peppe I don't think that is the issue here. The "setOverrideCursor" sets the cursor to be invisible for my app. Doing the same thing in the window show event won't change anything if this is a focus issue becuase I still need to get focus on my app :( Unless you are talking about a different method entirley?

Comment: Then force the window to have focus ASAP (activateWindow(), etc.)

Comment: @peppe Yes, but this is my question, how do I get focus on my window at startup... I tried activateWindow() and setFocus, but neither did it. Even on my windows simulator program the app was not in focus after running it...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
app.setCursorVisible(false);
```

may this help u.

Comment: Thanks for that, I am running Qt 4.6 and the app does not seem to have that function :(

Comment: None of the application classes have a `setCursorVisible` method. This used to be available through [QWSServer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwsserver.html) for embedded Linux. As of Qt 5.0 [QWS is no longer a supported platform](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/embedded-linux.html).